# What is function setInputFilter() in Laminas Framework and how can use it?

Tags: php, laminas

i have to learn about laminas framework for my job and got stuck about Forms and Action in https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/forms-and-actions/ 
As you can see

```
public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
{
    throw new DomainException(sprintf(
        '%s does not allow injection of an alternate input filter',
        __CLASS__
    ));
}
```

I dont understand why setInputFilter() have only 1 throw exception and dont know how it can be use. Can anybody explain it for me? Thank you so much

Comment: The doc page answers your question: The InputFilterAwareInterface defines two methods: setInputFilter() and getInputFilter(). We only need to implement getInputFilter() so we throw an exception from setInputFilter().

Comment: Yeah i read it but cant understand when use it and use for what? 
Because normal getter and setter not use like that

Comment: its not used. When you `implement` an `interface`, all methods must be implemented, regardless if you use them. Have a read of https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: Thank you so much, @LawrenceCherone! I misunderstanding with the same name function below. Have a good day!